# while importing psycopg2 i get the following error

Tags: python

import psycopg2

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "/Users/vedantwarekar/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/**init**.py",
>   line 51, in 
>       from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa ImportError:
>   dlopen(/Users/vedantwarekar/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-36m-darwin.so,
>   2): Symbol not found: _PQencryptPasswordConn   Referenced from:
>   /Users/vedantwarekar/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-36m-darwin.so
>   Expected in: /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib  in
>   /Users/vedantwarekar/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-36m-darwin.so

Comment: Try installing `psycopg2-binary` instead of `psycopg2`.  This _should_ avoid this type of problem.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I installed Postgresql on my mac with the app(POSGIS).

It was resolved upon loading with brew:

```
brew install postgresql@<version>
```